# Sinatra App as a Class - Why do this?

Tags: ruby, oop, sinatra

When reading the Sinatra docs I got the impression that all the routes and helpers just go into a single file. However, after reading a lot of the Sinatra questions and answers here on Stack, I see that most people are placing their routes and helper in a class. What benefits does this provide over a collection a blocks?

Edit: I get that putting router and helpers in their own modules is helpful but why should I have a class for the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Organization and reducing namespace pollution. When all my handlers are in the module `Handlers`, it's very clear what they all are, I can manipulate them as a group (iterate, redefine, etc.). Also, it reduces global namespace pollution by putting things in their own namespace.

Comment: I totally get the module concept, its the class object that doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: @Todd the same reasons apply to putting it in a class.